# Scrape first class node but not child using rvest

Tags: r, rvest

many questions on this but couldn't see the answer I'm looking for.

Looking to extract a specific text, with a class `.quoteText` which with my code works, but also extracts all of the child nodes within `.quoteText`:

```
url <- "https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/search?page=1&q=simone+de+beauvoir&utf8=%E2%9C%93"

quote_text <- function(html){

  path <- read_html(html)

  path %>% 
    html_nodes(".quoteText") %>%
    html_text(trim = TRUE) %>% 
    str_trim(side = "both") %>% 
    unlist()
}

quote_text(url)
```

with the result containing the text, but also every child node!

[image]

This is what the inspector tool brings up. What I'm looking for is the highlighted line, but not the sub-lines under the same code.

There must be a way to scrape only that line, no? Or will I need to collect that line, and remove the rest with a `str_extract` / regex?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like the CSS selectors support just getting the immediate text of the selected node, but `xpath` does. We can adjust your function to just extract the text with

```
quote_text <- function(html){

  path <- read_html(html)

  path %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath=paste(selectr::css_to_xpath(".quoteText"), "/text()") %>%
    html_text(trim = TRUE) %>% 
    str_trim(side = "both") %>% 
    unlist()
}
```

I convert the CSS selector to an xpath one and then append "/text()" to just get the text nodes of the elements.

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. I'll use the same technique to keep the title of the work as well as the text. Cheers!

Comment: Looking at a different .smallText node ("likes"), I can extract just the likes figureuseing the xpath= above again, but it includes all. How to select a specific node? I've added     #html_nodes(xpath = paste(selectr::css_to_xpath(".smallText"), ".a")) %>%

Comment: Comments aren't the right place to ask new questions. you can start a new post if you are having a different problem. If you are not trying to extract the immediate text, then you probably don't need the `css_to_xpath` thing. Maybe `path %>% html_nodes("a.smallText") %>% html_text()` is what you are looking for?

Comment: you're right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56496925/scrape-single-node-excluding-others-in-same-category

Comment: oops what you suggested worked. the question is there, I can give it a ^ if you'd like (or will just close it)